# Everything in my javascript file requires two clicks to trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

This is my whole JS.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


$('#ee_2_').css('fill', '#F26522');
$('#lt_2_').css('fill', '#F26522');
$('#lv_2_').css('fill', '#F26522');

//    $(".items .plusDelivered").hover(function(){
//        $(this).closest('.deliveredCategory');
//    })

$('.deliveredCategory').on('click mouseenter mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).find(".expandableClient").toggle();
    $(this).find('.plus-minus-toggle').toggleClass('collapsed');
    $(this).find('.dotHide').toggle();
});


$("#menu-primary-menu li").hover(function () {
    $('.navItems .menu-item a:before').css("display", 'inline-block');
});

$(window).on('mailsent.wpcf7', function () {
    $('.formFill').addClass('hide');
    $('.formSuccess').removeClass('hide')
});

$(window).on('wpcf7:invalid', function () {
    var epasts = $("input.epasts").val();
    var vards = $("input.vards").val();
    var uzvards = $("input.uzvards").val();
    var zina = $("textarea.zina").val();
    var talrunis = $("input.numurs").val();
    if (/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i.test(epasts) == !1) {
        $('input.epasts').css("border-color", 'red');
        $('input.epasts').css("color", 'red');
    }
    if (vards.length <= 2) {
        $('input.vards').css("border-color", 'red');
        $('input.vards').css("color", 'red');
    }
    if (uzvards.length <= 2) {
        $('input.uzvards').css("border-color", 'red');
        $('input.uzvards').css("color", 'red');
    }
    if (talrunis.length !== 0) {
        if (/^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/i.test(talrunis) == !1) {
            $('input.numurs').css("border-color", 'red');
            $('input.numurs').css("color", 'red');
        }
    }
    if (zina.length >= 10) {
       $(this).css("border-color", '#fed051');
        $(this).css("color", '#fed051');
        $('input.send').css("color", 'black');
    } else {

        $('.formContent .zina').css("border-color", 'red');
        $('.formContent .zina').css("color", 'red');
    }
    if ($(this).val().length > 10) {

        $(this).css("border-color", '#fed051');
        $(this).css("color", '#fed051');
        $('input.send').css("color", 'black');

        //           return false;
    } else {

        $(this).css("border-color", 'red');
        $(this).css("color", 'red');
    }
});

$("img.exit").click(function () {
    $('.popUpForm').addClass('hide')
});

$('.formContent input').click(function () {
    $(this).css("border-color", '#fed051');

});




$('.formContent input').blur(function () {

    if ($(this).val()) {

        $(this).css("border-color", '#fed051');
        $(this).css("color", '#fed051');
        $('input.send').css("color", 'black');

        //           return false;
    } else {

        $(this).css("border-color", 'black');
        $(this).css("color", 'black');
    }
});

$('.formContent .zina').blur(function () {

    if ($(this).val().length > 10) {

        $(this).css("border-color", '#fed051');
        $(this).css("color", '#fed051');
        $('input.send').css("color", 'black');

        //           return false;
    } else {

        $(this).css("border-color", 'red');
        $(this).css("color", 'red');
    }
});


$(".apply").click(function () {
    $('.popUpForm').removeClass('hide')
});



$('.accordion-item .heading').on('click mouseenter', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $content = $(this).next();
    $content.toggle();
    $('.accordion-item .content').not($content).hide();
    $('.accordion-item .heading').not(this).find('.plus-minus-toggle').addClass('collapsed')
    $(this).find('.plus-minus-toggle').toggleClass('collapsed');
}); 

$('.accordion-item .content').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $content = $(this).next();
    $content.toggle();
    $('.accordion-item .content').not($content).hide();
    $('.accordion-item .heading').not(this).find('.plus-minus-toggle').addClass('collapsed')
    $(this).find('.plus-minus-toggle').toggleClass('collapsed');
});

$(".full-service-cycle .accordion").mouseleave(function () {
    $('.plus-minus-toggle').addClass('collapsed');
    $('.accordion-item .content').hide();
});

$(".mobNav img").click(function () {
    if ($(".mobNav img").attr('src') == 'http://balticpremier.sem.lv/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/menu.png') {
        $(".mobNav img").attr('src', 'http://balticpremier.sem.lv/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/exit.png');
        $(".toggledOverlay").css("display", "block");
        $(".menuContainer").css("display", "block")
    } else {
        $(".mobNav img").attr('src', 'http://balticpremier.sem.lv/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/menu.png');
        $(".toggledOverlay").css("display", "none");
        $(".menuContainer").css("display", "none")
    }
});
$(".toggledOverlay").click(function () {
    $(this).css("display", 'none');
    $(".mobNav img").attr('src', 'http://balticpremier.sem.lv/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/menu.png');
    $(".menuContainer").css("display", "none")
});
$(".cls-6, .cls-5, .cls-4").css("fill", '#F26522');
$("#ee_2_").on('click mouseover', function () {
    $(this).css('fill', "#FABC14");
    $('#lv_2_').css('fill', '#F26522');
    $('#lt_2_').css('fill', '#F26522');
    $(".lv .latvian").addClass("hide");
    $(".lv .lithuanian").addClass("hide");
    $(".lv .estonian").removeClass("hide")
});
$("#lv_2_").on('click mouseover', function () {
    $(this).css('fill', "#FABC14");
    $(".lv .latvian").removeClass("hide");
    $(".lv .lithuanian").addClass("hide");
    $(".lv .estonian").addClass("hide");
    $('#lt_2_').css('fill', '#F26522');
    $('#ee_2_').css('fill', '#F26522')
});
$("#lt_2_").on('click mouseover', function () {
    $(".lv .latvian").addClass("hide");
    $(".lv .lithuanian").removeClass("hide");
    $(".lv .estonian").addClass("hide");
    $(this).css('fill', "#FABC14");
    $('#lv_2_').css('fill', '#F26522');
    $('#ee_2_').css('fill', '#F26522')
});
$(".area").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".lv .latvian").addClass("hide");
    $(".lv .lithuanian").addClass("hide");
    $(".lv .estonian").addClass("hide");
    $("#lt_2_").css('fill', "#F26522");
    $('#lv_2_').css('fill', '#F26522');
    $('#ee_2_').css('fill', '#F26522')
});
var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) {
    return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"
})(!window.safari || safari.pushNotification);
var isIE = !1 || !!document.documentMode;
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
if (isEdge == !0) {
    $(".map svg.chrome").removeClass("chrome").addClass("edge")
}
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS
});
```

Bear in mind that this is the javascript file for the whole site, but still, actions such as, opening hamburger menu, require 2 clicks to trigger.

It was working all the time, I did some changes a while ago and only now realized the issue, and now I don't recall what did I change.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I am talking only about the click actions, other actions work just fine.

Comment: What device are you using? Do you have any HTML or CSS?

Comment: which part of the code deals with *hamburger menu click*?

Comment: @gurvinder372 It's `$(".mobNav img").click`

Comment: That's why we want a [**minimal**, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) instead of a block of unrelated code where we first have to dig through to maybe find the problem.

Comment: @evolutionxbox The site can be found at http://balticpremier.sem.lv/en/, here is a virus scan if you need: https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/e2f05f0f4d6fde378f3f784c8c331849caef1e556fb1b173e4ac2f5ba521405c/detection

Try visiting through mobile and click 3 stripes on the top right hand side. You will need to click two times to open the menu. That happens everywhere where click event is present.

Comment: I'm sorry @Andreas, but I didn't want to remove any code because I could have removed the issue without knowing what was the cause and stumbling upon it in the future without knowing how to solve it.

Comment: What type of event is: `'mailsent.wpcf7'`??

Comment: Just a tip: I think you are pasting wayyyy too much code. Try to simplify it so it's easier to understand what's going on. That way you can get more help quicker :)

Comment: @zer00ne That is an event that is fired when the mail is confirmed to be sent successfully. It's a part of contact form 7 plugin in Wordpress.

Comment: WP is wacked you should put the word-puke tag up.

Comment: @zer00ne I'm sorry, but I don't understand? What do you mean by that?

Comment: "I didn't want to remove any code because I could have removed the issue without knowing what was the cause". If you do that gradually and systematically, and keep a track of changes (e.g. using source control, or just keeping notes) then that process should actually help you to _find_ the issue in the first place! Simple trial and error - strip the code back until the problem stops. Chances are you've found your problem, or at least got yourself in the right area to start digging.

Comment: @NKNz Note the newest edit to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because of your `if` statement in the below code:

```
$(".mobNav img").click(function () {
    if ($(".mobNav img").attr('src') == 'http://balticpremier.sem.lv/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/menu.png') {
        $(".mobNav img").attr('src', 'http://balticpremier.sem.lv/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/exit.png');
        $(".toggledOverlay").css("display", "block");
        $(".menuContainer").css("display", "block")
    } else {
        $(".mobNav img").attr('src', 'http://balticpremier.sem.lv/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/menu.png');
        $(".toggledOverlay").css("display", "none");
        $(".menuContainer").css("display", "none")
    }
});
```

Your original `src` of the image is `/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/menu.png` and not `http://balticpremier.sem.lv/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/menu.png`

Change it to the following to fix it:

```
$(".mobNav img").click(function () {
    if ($(".mobNav img").attr('src') == 'http://balticpremier.sem.lv/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/menu.png' || $(".mobNav img").attr('src') == '/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/menu.png') {
        $(".mobNav img").attr('src', 'http://balticpremier.sem.lv/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/exit.png');
        $(".toggledOverlay").css("display", "block");
        $(".menuContainer").css("display", "block")
    } else {
        $(".mobNav img").attr('src', 'http://balticpremier.sem.lv/wp-content/themes/balticpremier/assets/menu.png');
        $(".toggledOverlay").css("display", "none");
        $(".menuContainer").css("display", "none")
    }
});
```

A tip: when facing issues like these try to open the Chrome Developer Tools and observe what happens when you click the link. In your case you can see the `src`change in the first click.